# How to extract from a plot object with shaded regions the (x,y) coordinate vectors that demark the upper and lower region boundaries?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose we have this ggplot code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gcookbook)   # heightweight data set is from gcookbook

# Two loess lines, one for males and for females; factor is in aes():
ggplot(data = heightweight, aes(x = ageYear, y = heightIn, color = sex)) +
  theme_bw() +
  # females with Venus symbol in red, males with Mars symbol in blue:
  geom_point( shape = if_else(heightweight$sex=="f", "\u2640", "\u2642"),
              size = 3,
              color = if_else(heightweight$sex=="f", "red", "blue")) +
  geom_smooth() -> p
```

Apart from the points themselves, there are 6 sets of (x,y) coordinates of interest: the Loess curve for the females for height as a function of age, the upper boundary of the Loess curve for females, the lower boundary of the Loess curve for females, and the three analogous curves for males.

`str(p)` gives a list of 9 for this example, but I'm a bit lost in its output.

If we look at `str(p)` we see a long and complicated listing of the elements of the graph object p.  It is unclear to me how to extract these 6 sets of (x,y) coordinates from p, in order to do other interesting things with them.  For example, for the upper and lower curves for the female Loess fit:

```
p.Loess.F.upper <- p$<.. not sure what goes here ..>
p.Loess.F.lower <- p$<.. not sure what goes here ..>
```

Is there a good explanation out there of what these elements are for the nitty-gritty innards of a ggplot object?  Or also for other similar but not ggplot objects?

Comment: You need to realise that ggplot uses the functions `loess` and `predict` to create the plot. Extracting the data from the plot is adding an extra layer of complexity that isn't required - simply call the `loess` function on your data to get the model, and `predict` the results.

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot2` provides some easy to use helper functions to extract some of the elements of the `ggplot` object, e.g. to extract the data underlying the geom layers you could use `layer_data()` like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gcookbook)

p <- ggplot(data = heightweight, aes(x = ageYear, y = heightIn, color = sex)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(
    aes(
      shape = ifelse(sex == "f", "\u2640", "\u2642")
    ),
    size = 3
  ) +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_shape_identity() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(f = "red", m = "blue"))

# Get the data for the second layer aka the geom_smooth
loess_data <- layer_data(p, i = 2)
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x'

head(loess_data)
#>   colour        x        y     ymin     ymax        se flipped_aes PANEL group
#> 1    red 11.58000 56.48653 54.84195 58.13111 0.8295025       FALSE     1     1
#> 2    red 11.65494 56.78483 55.33671 58.23295 0.7304102       FALSE     1     1
#> 3    red 11.72987 57.07438 55.80040 58.34836 0.6425766       FALSE     1     1
#> 4    red 11.80481 57.35437 56.22898 58.47976 0.5676327       FALSE     1     1
#> 5    red 11.87975 57.62401 56.61873 58.62929 0.5070490       FALSE     1     1
#> 6    red 11.95468 57.88258 56.96714 58.79803 0.4617375       FALSE     1     1
#>     fill linewidth linetype weight alpha
#> 1 grey60         1        1      1   0.4
#> 2 grey60         1        1      1   0.4
#> 3 grey60         1        1      1   0.4
#> 4 grey60         1        1      1   0.4
#> 5 grey60         1        1      1   0.4
#> 6 grey60         1        1      1   0.4

p.Loess.F.upper <- loess_data |> 
  subset(group == 1, select = ymax, drop = TRUE)

head(p.Loess.F.upper)
#> [1] 58.13111 58.23295 58.34836 58.47976 58.62929 58.79803
```